# What does “TopicDisallowed” error reason in APNS?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Explained in Apple's Development APNS Document:

> TopicDisallowed is 'Pushing to this topic is not allowed.'
>
> 'The topic is currently the bundle identifier of the target application on an iOS device.'
>
> So TopicDisallowed means bundle identifier disable?
>
> Our App is off the shelf in the Apple Store，but we can use old apns protocol to push。

Comment: Did you find the answer for this question?